# html form still showing validation errors even after entering right values with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a contact form including validations. Everything is working very well but  I have only one issue. An old shown error is not going away when submitting the form another time.

Here is the part of the document I have with the javascript:

```
<form  id="contactForm" th:action="@{/contact}" th:method="POST" entype="utf8"  >
<label   class="form-control-label on-fonts-style display-7" >Name</label>
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="full name" name="fullName" required="required" >

<label  class="form-control-label on-fonts-style display-7" >Email</label> 
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" 
name="email" value="" required="required">
<span id="emailError" style="color:#F41F0E"></span>

<label   class="form-control-label on-fonts-style display-7" >Phone</label>
<input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="phone" 
value="">

<label   class="form-control-label on-fonts-style display-7" >Message</label>
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" rows="7"> 
</textarea>
<span id="messageError" style="color:#F41F0E"></span>

<span id="globalError" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-4" 
style="display:none" ></span>

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form display- 
4">SEND FORM</button>
</form>

<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script th:inline="javascript">
var serverContext = [[@{/}]];

  $(document).ready(function () {       
      $('form').submit(function(event) {

    registerContact(event);

      });
});
function registerContact(event){

event.preventDefault();
$(".alert").html("").hide();
$(".error-list").html("");


var formData= $('form').serialize();
$.post(serverContext + "contact",formData ,function(data){


  if(data.message == "success"){
      window.location.href = serverContext + "successContact.html";
    }
})

.fail(function(data) {
  if(data.responseJSON.error.indexOf("MailError") > -1)
  {
      window.location.href = serverContext + "emailError.html";
  }
  else if(data.responseJSON.error.indexOf("InternalError") > -1){
      window.location.href = serverContext + "login?message=" + data.responseJSON.message;
  }
  else{
    var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseJSON.message);
      $.each( errors, function( index,item ){
          $("#"+item.field+"Error").show().html(item.defaultMessage);
      });
      errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseJSON.error);
      $.each( errors, function( index,item ){
          $("#globalError").show().append(item.defaultMessage+"<br/>");
      });
  }
});
}
</script>
```

Let me explain: I have two validations (on message and email), so if I typed them wrong the two errors show up. However if I fixed one of them and submit again the old error is still there. Even if I fix them both and submit the form, the form will be submitted but with still showing the errors.

Please anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you include these errors in your post?

Comment: Hide the error containers first before doing the validation

Comment: thank you @Gezzasa your idea sounds very helpful, can you guide us through this and answer the question?

Comment: what is your `var serverContext = [[@{/}]];` variable holding, its not a valid JavaScript variable initialization

Comment: I don't have enough time at the moment to code it but basically, you show the error but you'll need to hide it if it has been corrected. When you do the validation and hide all errors (Give them all a class of `error` or something and hide `error`) then validate and show what is necessary. Hope this helps :D..............Got some time haha. hope the answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class for all the error spans called `error` as an example.

when you get to the error checking part you can first hide all errors

`$(".error").hide()`

and then carry on with the validation as normal :)